# How can I install the PowerShell module for SkypeforBusiness?

Tags: windows, powershell, skype, windows-server-2016, skype-for-business

Trying to install the PowerShell module called "SkypeforBusiness"

The PowerShell module is installed on the server where Skype is currently running but I want to install the module on a different server.

The Skype version is Skype for Business Server 2015

Microsoft mentions the module in the following article.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/skypeforbusiness/manage/management-shell

I have tried the following

```
Find-Module -Name "SkypeforBusiness"
```

I receive the error: No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name.

I am guessing I don't have the correct PSRepository installed?

Comment: Do you have Skype for Business installed? Note that this is _not_ the same as the consumer Skype that used to be an independent company. If you have Skype for Business installed, the module should also have been installed, and you should be able to load it into a standard PowerShell session with `Import-Module`, as the linked page states.

Comment: Sorry, I'll update my post. I need the module on a different server and it's Skype for Business Server 2015.

Comment: On the server where it's installed, start up PowerShell or the Skype for Business Server Management Shell, and check the value of `$env:psmodulepath`. The module you're looking for should be in one of the directories named there; however, note that cmdlets in the module _may_ be implemented such that they make calls to Skype for Business Server DLLs, which may not be available if the module is copied to another computer without the product installed.